# Angular share navbarComponent to another Component

Tags: angular, navbar, file-structure

I am asking how can I share my nav menu-dashboard Component (inside shared/Layout) with dashboard component and all components inside dashboard Component such as Courses component and I have a module for dashboard component with routing.

**Dashboard Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module';
import { CoursesComponent } from './courses/courses.component';


@NgModule({
declarations: [CoursesComponent],
imports: [
CommonModule,
DashboardRoutingModule
]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

I declared DashboardModule  inside AppModule:

[image]

Comment: Could you share the stackblitz ?

Comment: have nav-menu-dashboard a module ?

Comment: no module for nav-menu-dashboard i declared in appModule

Comment: You could create a module nav-menu-dashboard and import to the dashboard module, after you need just to import the component where you need inside dashboard folder.

Comment: thank you for your answer...but what i need is put the  nav-menu-dashboard inside dashboardComponent.html and all folders inside dashboard folder takes this nav...like if i put it in appComponent.html the whole app will take the  nav-menu-dashboard component

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following inside you DashboardComponent.html

```
<nav-menu-dashboard #navigation></nav-menu-dashboard>
```

And in the DashboardComponent.ts, add the following:

```
@ViewChild('navigation', {static: false}) navigationComponent: NavMenuDashboardComponent;
```

you can access methods and other properties inside navigationComponent by implementing the ViewChild method.

Comment: thank you for your answer..but what is naviagtionComponent and how can display  nav-menu-dashboard inside dashboard component and whole folders inside dashboard folder

Comment: 'navigation' is reference (directive) to NavMenuDashboard -> declared in html. 'navigationComponent' is just variable declaration that's pointing to your NavMenuDashboardComponent. When you say you need whole folders inside dashboard, what do you meant ? Probably I'm not understanding your question. The shared folder you have is correct and the child components you wanted to use should be declared in the parent Module, In your case DashBoard Module, not else where (app module). If duplication occurs. I think you need to rethink about the DashBoard module